# A Vocabulary word meaning: " to completely embody the meaning of a term "

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, synonyms

Example:
( a really REALLY bad situation )

> This situation __ FUBAR

Some synonyms I can come up with:

> embodies
>   exemplifies

Comment: The definition of irony: Not knowing the difference between a definition and an example.

Comment: So what is wrong with the "synonyms" you have already? Did you plug them into a thesaurus and fail to find anything useful? A good question of this type should explain what you tried to do, *and why it didn't work for you* - you've got the first part, but... what's wrong with the results you came up with?

Comment: @delinquentme, Some of the answers at http://english.stackexchange.com/q/100814/8278 may be applicable.

Answer (score 12):

How about "epitome."

> "This situation is the epitome of FUBAR."

If you want a verb, there's "epitomizes", but I like the noun better.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another answer: [quintessence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quintessence), sense 1, "A thing that is the most perfect example of its type; the most perfect embodiment of something."

A related term is [paradigm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paradigm), sense 1, "An example serving as a model or pattern; a template."

Answer (score 1):

> **encompasses**

Means to entirely cover something.

In the same register as 'FUBAR', one would use the phrasing:

> This  situation **is totally** FUBAR.

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked "embodies" and "incarnate."

> "This situation embodies FUBAR."
>
> "This situation is FUBAR incarnate."

Answer (score 1):

"exemplifies" is a great term for this, as it refers to providing an example.

*illustrates* and *depicts* will also work here.

Answer (score 1):

> This situation **defines** FUBAR.

If you want to completely embody the meaning of a term then I would reason that the situation is a definition for the term so therefore it defines it.

Giving an example by illustration or comparison by epitome seem to be one step removed from a complete embodiment or definition.

If you're not keen on the verb then go this way:

> This situation is, **the definition of**, FUBAR.

Comment: See my comment for this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you're talking about someone rather than something or some situation, you can use **personifies** or one of its other forms....

> Charles is the very personification of narrow-mindedness.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to all of the above.

Boil it down.

> This situation **is** FUBAR.

I think the word "is" **is** what what you're after.