# What is a good word for “best example”?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good word for “best example”? I would like to describe a film as the *greatest example* of its features.

Answer (score 35):

I would suggest *[epitome](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epitome?view=uk)*.

> (the epitome of) a person or thing that is a perfect example of a particular quality or type: *she looked the epitome of elegance and good taste*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 22):

How about Exemplar [1](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exemplar?q=exemplar) (if you need a noun)

> a person or thing serving as a typical example or appropriate model: *the place is an exemplar of multicultural Britain*

Or Exemplary [2](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exemplar?q=exemplary) if adjective

> serving as a desirable model; very good:  *exemplary behaviour*

Answer (score 16):

Dictionary.com defines [paragon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/paragon) as

> a model or pattern of excellence or of a particular excellence: *a paragon of virtue*.

---

EDIT: Current usage of *paragon* in the context of films:

[Casablanca](http://www.slantmagazine.com/dvd/review/casablanca/2264):

> ...leading as it does to the most famous movie scene of all time, is held up as a paragon for subsequent generations of aspiring screenwriters...

[Black Swan](http://www.behindthehype.com/movie-reviews/drama-review/black-swan/): (blog title) "Dramatic Film Paragon."

Comment: I love the word Paragon (the exemplar, the best or the creator of its genre) and its antithesis Epigone (the also rans, imitations, pale copies)

Comment: "Epigone" is a new one for me! ("undistinguished scions of mighty ancestors") Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Besides *epitome*, you might also want to consider,

- [Ultimate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ultimate): **2** being the **best** or **most extreme example** of its kind: *the ultimate accolade*
- [Quintessence](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quintessence): **1** the **most perfect** or **typical example** of a quality or class: *he was the quintessence of political professionalism*

Comment: I think '*quintessential*' is the form they're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22archetypal%20zombie%20movie%22&oq=%22archetypal%20zombie%20movie%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.52245730&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are 5880 references to the ***archetypal*** zombie movie, for example.

[archetype:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetype) *the original pattern or model of which all things of the same type are representations or copies : prototype; also : **a perfect example***.

Alternatives such *pre-eminent, paragon, epitome,* and even *exemplar* almost always have strong positive connotations. They don't work for a good example of something bad, such as an [archetypal serial killer](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22archetypal%20serial%20killer%22&oq=%22archetypal%20serial%20killer%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.1515&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: That would be more to do with it setting a pattern. You couldn't say "28 days later" was an archetypal zombie movie, since the genre was so well-established already (you might argue it's the archetypal "fast-zombie" movie). Conversely, you couldn't argue "I Walked with a Zombie" was an archetypal zombie movie, as while it was very early, and a great film (personally my favourite zombie movie) the genre didn't follow it at all (indeed, it says something that it's my favourite - I don't like zombie movies). "Night of the Living Dead" on the other hand is a candidate because it was so-copied.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: You can certainly produce an archetypal xxxx long after the first xxxx's were made. I'm sure lots of movie directors have set out to produce, for example, the [archetypal western movie](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22archetypal+western+movie%22&oq=%22archetypal+western+movie%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.850&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but obviously for most of them the genre had been long-established before they made their attempt. [Unforgiven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105695/) is an archetypal western to my mind.

Comment: What followed it, that made it an archetype?
For that matter, "Citizen Kane", "Seventh Seal" and Derek Jarman's "Blue" are all great films I would say were not archetypal because nothing could ever copy them (though some performances and scenes in the first two where archetypal). Their very greatness is counter to their ever being archetypal.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: You're ignoring M-W's alternate definition, *a perfect example*, which I'm perfectly comfortable with in modern casual conversation. The closely-related *pattern, model* sense isn't the only one people use, regardless of whether you think they should.

Comment: It's not another definition, it's part of the definition of the same sense. I'm not at all comfortable using it for part of a definition when it's at odds with the crux of it. Were it a separate sense, that might be a different thing.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I'm not trying to persuade you to change the way *you* use the word. Just to accept that in practice lots of people use it in a way that's more synonymous with, say, *quintessential* than with *ancestral, prototypical*.

Answer (score 7):

"A is the *[quintessential](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quintessential?q=quintessential) example* of B."

> quintessential - adjective
>
> representing the most perfect or typical example of a quality or class: he was the quintessential tough guy—strong, silent, and self-contained

Comment: It's very helpful to our community if you can edit your answer to include the definition for your word.  Thanks!

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Sure thing. I've edited my response.

Answer (score 4):

"Par excellence". Usually placed after, rather than before the category you are claiming it is the best of, as per its original French use:

> *Pretty Village, Pretty Flame* is the gritty war-movie par excellence.

It's a "still foreign-enough" loan-word that many people would italicise it in use.

*Pre-eminent* might also serve, though it more reflects how a film is seen, and its standing, so if you disagree with the general public, or the film you are going to describe is under-rated in your view, then it won't work:

> *Cross of Iron* is the pre-eminent gritty war-movie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the phrase "**Exhibit A**". Some other examples:

Try "**paradigmatic example**". E.g.:

> [**§**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/paradigmatic) Hot dogs are the paradigmatic *[example of]* American food.
>
> [**§**](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2016/mar/02/cult-of-memory-when-history-does-more-harm-than-good) It was a paradigmatic example of what happens when collective memory born of trauma finds political and, above all, military expression.

Try "**textbook example**" [[*cf.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22textbook+case%22+is%3Aq)]. E.g.:

> [**§**](https://www.thetrace.org/2015/12/straw-purchase-supreme-court-san-bernardino/) At first glance, Marquez’s actions were a textbook “straw purchase,” in which a person buys a gun for someone else ...
>
> [**§**](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/wp/2016/06/07/ryan-says-trumps-attacks-on-judge-fit-the-textbook-definition-of-a-racist-comment/) Pressed by a reporter on how he can support Trump in spite of his “textbook” racist comments, ...

..and:

> He's pretty much a textbook case *(example)* of ACOA. [(in reference to the [13 characteristics](http://acabdf.weebly.com/blog--articles/adult-children-of-alcoholics-acoa-the-13-characteristics-a-2010-article))]

Try "**exemplifying example**" [[*cf.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22textbook+case%22+is%3Aq)]. E.g.:

> [**§**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exemplified) The plays of Wilde exemplify the comedy of manners.
>
> [**§**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exemplify) This painting perfectly exemplifies the naturalistic style which was so popular at the time.
>
> [**§**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exemplify) a dish that exemplifies French cuisine
>
> His works exemplify the taste of the period.

..and:

> [**§**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+exemplified) the best dry sherry is exemplified by the fino of Jerez
>
> [**§**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiler_room_(business)#Modern_boiler_rooms) A boiler room operation is well exemplified by the case of Fort Lauderdale-based company First Resource Group LLC charged by the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission with conducting a fraudulent boiler room scheme in 2012.

Try "**customary example**".

Try "**symbolic example**". E.g.:

> [**§**](http://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/jun/28/no-sanctuary-deportation-migrants-limbo) Jane Doe first moved 10 months ago to avoid deportation. Now she's become a symbol of paralysis in immigration reform.

Try "**paragon**". E.g.:

> [**§**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/paragon) The Southern accents were molasses-thick, and the diner setting made the sitcom "Alice" seem like a paragon of comic subtlety.

Answer (score 0):

The best example of a film should be **a masterpiece**,* a work of outstanding artistry and skill*.