# What alternatives are there for the popular and ubiquitous use of the word "iconic"?

Tags: synonyms

In light of how frequently people seem to be using the word *iconic* today, what are some alternatives which are perhaps more apt and more accurate?  I've always associated the word with paintings in a church, which have that certain iconic look to them. I guess you'd call it a signature- or highly stylized look, and not very realistic.

I've provided a few "before and after" examples below, but I welcome suggestions for improvement; that is, better alternatives. Possibly you prefer the word *iconic* and would not seek to substitute another word for it. That's OK too.

> The O. J. Simpson trial is *the* iconic controversial trial from the 90s.

vs.

> The O. J. Simpson trial is representative of controversial trials from the 90s.

or

> Snowboarder Joe Schmo's performance in the 2014 Winter Olympics was iconic for that relatively new event.

vs.

> Snowboarder Joe Schmo's performance in the 2014 Winter Olympics was the quintessence of that relatively new event.

or

> The iconic romantic comedy from the 90s has to be "Four Weddings and a Funeral," starring Andie McDowell and Hugh Grant.

vs.

> "Four Weddings and a Funeral," starring Andie McDowell and Hugh Grant, is the epitome of romantic comedies from the 90s.

Perhaps the appropriate alternative word or expression varies from context to context. If so, could you also explain grammatically why that is so? I'm not much of a grammarian, so please be simplistic, if possible.

Comment: This looks to me like a dup of [What is a good word for “best example”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100814/), but I'm all out of closevotes. Anyway, [here's the evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=iconic&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ciconic%3B%2Cc0) to support OP's "how frequently people seem to be using the word *iconic* today". Prevalence really has increased astonishingly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Downvote? Me? I'm hurt deeply. (Just kidding.)

Comment: Seriously, I wouldn't *dream* of ***downvoting*** a perfectly good question like this. I admit I might be tempted to downvote the umpteenth question on [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/), but even there one has to bear in mind that the crappy built-in "site search" facility is a bit worthless when it specifically *excludes* the very words *(a/an)* you'd be likely to search for. But surely you'll admit that ***iconic*** is a highly relevant (and, strangely, *missing*) word for that earlier question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It sure seems to be the **iconic** word for this generation!

Answer (score 2):

An icon was originally a picture or representation of a saint or Christ. One of the reasons icons have been condemned by certain churches/religions is that they were venerated themselves as sacred. I agree that the word *icon* is used all too easily by people, who often exaggerate for effect. I would use a less exagerrative replacement.

What to use instead? One understated way of saying something similar in meaning is *the picture*, *the image*, *models* and *typifies* or is the *essence* of: Four Weddings... is *the picture* of romantic comedies from the 90s.

The perfect example: Four Weddings... is *the perfect example* of romantic comedies from the 90s.

Those don't hype it too much.

If you want the perfect word, context is important.

[*Epitome*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/epitome): typical of or possessing to a high degree the features of a whole class (*exemplification*, *quintessence/quintessential*, and *the ultimate* are also dramatic words to express the idea.)

I think the [*apotheosis*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apotheosis) is an amusing way of reflecting on the hype: the elevation or exaltation to the rank of a god.

If you don't like *iconic*, maybe considering the less lofty words for *representative* would suit you.

Comment: The problem with most of these words is that they tend to have *positive* associations. When you're talking about something like OJ's acquittal (which I admit I didn't follow too closely at the time, but which I assume was a gross miscarriage of justice), you probably don't want those positive associations. That's why I think *archetype* is a fitting word. You can have an archetypal serial killer *and* an archetypal philanthropist when it's used in the modern "perfect example" sense (where even "perfect" there has potentially unwanted positive overtones).

Comment: I agree that many of these carry a positive connotation. Archetype, to me, carries a religious or literary connotation. *Prototypical* carries the connotation of *first*. It supports choosing words carefully to suit the occassion.

Comment: @Susan: Well, it seems to me that saying something [*is the archetypal](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+the+archetypal&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20archetypal%3B%2Cc0) [whatever it's the perfect example of]* has become vastly more popular during my lifetime. Even more so for [***he** was the archetypal*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+the+archetypal&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20the%20archetypal%3B%2Cc0) - probably often a "loose" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Archetypical is now favored nearly 3 to 1 over archetypal at ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+the+archetypal%2Carchetypical&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20archetypal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carchetypical%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @WayfaringStranger: Your statement truly boggled me, given that I'd tend to regard *archetypical* as no more than an ignorant affectation (OED does have a listing for it, but all it does is provide a few citations to prove it exists, and point you back to the full definitions under *archetypal*). Actually, your NGrams is misleading because you compared the single word *archetypical* to the string *"is the archetypal"*. If you make it a "fair fight" (one-on-one words) the picture looks...

Comment: [completely different](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=archetypal%2Carchetypical&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carchetypal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carchetypical%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Susan - Prototypical also carries the connotation of imperfect or unfinished.

Comment: @Oldcat - yes, it does, doesn't it! Sometimes it's like I'm a stranger in my own language; another pair of eyes is illuminating. Thanks. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: True, the comparison of phrase to word was improper. However, no matter how much I dislike the term, usage of archetypical has been rising in recent decades.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - what an awful word. It makes me think someone said *archetypal* incorrectly, and a new word was born. Very interesting!

Comment: @Susan: Actually, I find archetypal kinda good. It can mean, after all, "perfect or typical as a specimen of something" (Dictionary.com, definition 1). It's a little highfalutin, but if I hear "iconic" one more time I think I'll start kicking some &^%$# and taking names!

Answer (score 1):

***Historic*** could be used instead of *iconic* to suggest a top athlete's performance as being particularly memorable as in:

The ice-figure champions [Jayne Torvill and Dean Thomson's](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-26180407) **historic free programme** performed to Ravel's Bolero at Sarajevo winter Olympics 1984, which earned the couple 12 perfect 6.0 marks. A feat never achieved either before or since, three decades on.

Many supporters would call Torvil and Dean the **emblems** of British ice-skating

Or for a team such as: The **emblematic Jamaica bobsleigh team** at Calgary 1988, who still represent the concept of the underdog who comes out on top or if you prefer, whose popularity and simpatia outshine their actual performance.

Vocabulary.com gives a good explanation on its [use](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/emblematic):

> **Something emblematic is symbolic. Empty buildings are emblematic of a
>   city in decline, and a crown is emblematic of royalty.**
>
> If you know
>   that an emblem is a visual symbol, then you won't be surprised that
>   emblematic things stand for other things. In fact, the word emblem
>   comes from the French word for symbol. Something emblematic represents
>   a larger issue, good or bad. Sometimes emblematic is used for things
>   that are excellent examples. An A student is an emblematic student,
>   and a war hero is an emblematic soldier. Emblematic people are symbols
>   of what others aspire to be.